# Object object is showing instead of data using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am new in Angular and I am doing a web service request to populate a table. I am using the *ngFor to populate my table. I receive my email correctly but the other elements in tree show as [Object object]

This is my JSON response:

```
{
    "data": [  
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "jose@hotmail.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$44ghfG4Ym4COxXbj9pDBuOLBXCPRRDiIM7y77G.XEh7avm2GOxlUC",
            "isAdmin": 0,
            "acessTypes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "accessTypeName": "User",
                    "subAcessTypeName": "Ver&Escrever"
                }
            ],
            "tomas": [],
            "consultas": [],
            "profile": "NORMALUSER"
        }
    ],
    "dataArray": null,
    "errors": []
}
```

This is my Angular Code´

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Tipo de acesso</th>
            <th>SubTipo de acesso</th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let user of listUser">
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.acessTypes}}</td>
            <td>{{user.acessTypes}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

This is my User component

```
findAll(){
    this.userService.findAll().subscribe((responseApi: ResponseApi)=>{
      this.listUser = responseApi['data'];
    }, err => {
      this.showMessage({
        type: 'error',
        text: err['error']['error'][0]
      });
     }
    )
  }
```

Comment: If you add `json` pipe, that should show you full data `<td>{{user.acessTypes | json}}</td>`. But you definitely need another loop over there to access individual object properties

Comment: if you simply want to see the all the elements in the array, just use the json pipe like `<td>{{ user.acessTypes | json }}</td>`

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I just want to see the name and the accessType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, because `user.acessTypes` is an array of object.

You need to access specific values from object.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of listUser">
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let i of user.acessTypes">{{i.accessTypeName}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let i of user.acessTypes">{{i.subAcessTypeName}}</td>
</tr>
```

or using one inner loop.

```
    <tr *ngFor="let user of listUser">
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
               <ng-container *ngFor="let i of user.acessTypes" >
                <td>{{i.accessTypeName}}</td>
                <td>{{i.subAcessTypeName}}</td>
               </ng-container>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Nope, because it return an empty string :)

Comment: an object will contain empty string as well. :)

Comment: The problem is that the object(as you can see in the JSON request) does not contain an empty string

Comment: that's an array so you need to use indexing over the accessTypes.

Comment: Thanks thats it :)

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: @DheerajKumar Why two loops? When you can do it using one.

Comment: sure, we can use span or angular directives like ng-container.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `json` pipe, that should show you full data `<td>{{user.acessTypes | json}}</td>`

But you have to loop through `acessTypes` array to access individual object properties

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Tipo de acesso</th>
        <th>SubTipo de acesso</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of listUser">
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let type of user.acessTypes">
        <td>{{type.accessTypeName}}</td>
         <td>{{type.subAcessTypeName}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qulbvk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks, very helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

`user.acessTypes` is an array.

Use index as below.

```
<td>{{user.acessTypes[0].accessTypeName}}</td>
<td>{{user.acessTypes[0].subAcessTypeName}}</td>
```

Comment: But the user can have more than one accessType :)

Comment: As in one of the comments, then you would need another ngFor

Comment: Can you show an example on how to do a nested ngFor?